# Need libca.so (Needed to install epics)

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I need to install epics on my Ubuntu system, but when I try to it returns a warning saying it cannot find the dynamic library (libca.so or libCom.so).  I tried to locate them, but it appears that they do not exist on my system.  How can I get them on there?  I thought they should automatically be there?

This is really the symptom of a larger problem I'm having when I try to run the program I am working with.  That gives me the following error:

> ```
> OSError: /dls_sw/epics/R3.14.8.2/base/lib/linux-x86/libca.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```

I figured I got this because I need to install epics, but I can't do that because libca.so doesn't exist on my system...

<sub>I'm fairly new to all this so hopefully this all makes sense.</sub>

Comment: A little googling shows that libca is part of EPICS. What did you do to install EPICS? It seems that you already have it under `/dls_sw/epics`; is there a `libca.so` there? What is the output of `uname -m`, and of `file /path/to/the/program/you/want/to/run`?